# using python Selenium .text with russian letters

Tags: python, selenium, unicode

I use selenium .text attribute to get some text from a div,

```
message_text = message.find_element_by_class_name("im_msg_text").text
```

and if I use

```
print message_text
```

I get:

```
'message_text': u'\u043a\u0430\u043a\u043e\u0439-\u0442\u043e \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442'
```

The question is how can I convert it to normal string containing russian letters?

Comment: instaed of using `.text` try to use `.getText()`

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`print u"{}".format(message_text)` or use decoding.